# How to format Json data into desired format and iterate through the loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm studying JSON, so I'm kinda confused with data format, array, object and string.

**First of all, I need data in this format (in jQuery page)**.  Is this object or array?

```
var data = [[2015-10-29 11:35:33, 315.71], [2015-10-29 11:36:33, 317.45], [2015-10-29 11:38:52, 317.50], [2015-10-29 11:42:08, 315.86], [2015-10-29 11:43:32, 314.93], [2015-10-29 11:50:00, 313.19], [2015-10-29 11:35:33, 313.34]];
```

**But I'm getting like this (in PHP page)**. Is this string?

```
 var data = [{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:35:33"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:36:33"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:37:31"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:38:34"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:38:52"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:39:15"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:42:08"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:42:48"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:43:32"},{"bv ":"27590","datey ":"2015-10-29 11:50:00"}];
```

**When I receive `data` (from PHP page like above)** **in jQuery page via ajax,**

[image]

SO am I getting the data in the right format that I wanted `[[2015-10-29 11:35:33, 315.71], [2015-10-29 11:36:33, 317.45]]` and how do I iterate through this array of data?

Someone help me understand the data format involved here and the way iterate through them.

I tried:

1)

```
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
   alert(data.[i].datey);//says undefined
}
```

2)

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].datey);//doesn't show any alert
    })
```

This is my ajax and PHP script for your reference:

```
$(function(){
  var data;
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'query_sales.php',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    /*$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].datey);
    });​*/
    }//close success
  });//close ajax
});//close function
```

PHP script:

```
$acceptedUser = new search();
$sales = $acceptedUser->get_sales_graph();
$before = array();
foreach($sales as $k=>$v)
{

    array_push($before,array("bv "=>$v['total_bv'],"datey "=>$v['as_of_date']));

}
echo json_encode($before);
```

Comment: `2015-10-29 11:35:33` in the array would cause errors.

Comment: on the part where you tried `$.each` have you tried `alert(item.datey)`?

Comment: @roullie, I did like, alert(data[i].datey);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try change this:

```
array_push($before,array("bv"=>$v['total_bv'],"datey"=>$v['as_of_date']));
//--------------------------^^---------------------^^--you have spaces in your keys
```

Then in the success function you can do this:

```
success: function(data){
    var arr = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
       arr.push([item.bv, item.datey])
    });    
}
```

checkout the sample below:

```js
var data = [{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:35:33"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:36:33"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:37:31"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:38:34"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:38:52"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:39:15"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:42:08"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:42:48"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:43:32"},{"bv":"27590","datey":"2015-10-29 11:50:00"}];
var arr = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    arr.push([+item.bv, item.datey])
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it works. Can you name the data format I got initially and the one I wanted please, just for my knowledge?

Comment: you  don't have any decimal values in your json as i see. although you can  use `+item.bv` and `+item.datey` to convert the values to numbers. but time with `:` would create issues for you, better to leave it as string representation as it is now.

Comment: @Vani See my answer for your question about the naming.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `var data` is not valid. Your second one is an array of objects.

You tried:

```
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
   alert(data.[i].datey);//says undefined
}
```

but your property name is "datey ", not "datey". So you will have to access it like this:

```
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
   alert(data.[i]["datey  "]);
}
```

Or better, fix your PHP to remove the extra spaces:

```
array_push($before,array("bv"=>$v['total_bv'],"datey"=>$v['as_of_date']));
```

Comment: but why the first one is not valid yeah?

Comment: Because you have two types of data: string and number. And your first `var data` has values like `2015-10-29 11:35:33` that are not string (because they are not surrounded by quotations) and not numbers (because they have additional characters like the space). If you surround all of them with quotations, they will become valid, but still not really good JSON because they are not named.

Comment: now I got it. Are you able to help me on this. A new question I asked and now I think its closely related to the data format issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494970/graph-in-flot-js-not-formed-via-data-that-supplied-through-ajax?noredirect=1#comment54773948_33494970

Comment: Your question is closed.

Comment: refer to this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495669/data-supplied-for-flot-js-via-ajax-says-undefined