# Data supplied for flot.js via ajax says undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In the below, script I'm getting data from database to form a line graph. But the data says `undefined` and no graph is formed.

```
var d;
var arr = [];

$(function() {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'query_sales.php',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                arr.push([item.datey, +item.bv]);
            }); 
            d = arr; //JSON.stringify(arr);
        }
    });

    alert(d); //says undefined

    $.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
        xaxis: { mode: "time" }
    });

    $("#whole").click(function () {
        $.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
            xaxis: { mode: "time" }
        });
    });

    // Add the Flot version string to the footer
    $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
});
```

This is how I'm querying the database and sending json object to ajax via PHP script

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
$acceptedUser = new search();
$sales = $acceptedUser->get_sales_graph();
$before = array();
foreach($sales as $k=>$v)
{
    $date = strtotime($v['as_of_date']) * 1000;
    array_push($before, array("datey" => $date, "bv" => $v['total_bv']));
}
echo json_encode($before);
```

However if I use dummy data like this in the place of var d graph formed and data shown. I would like to understand the difference between this dummy data and the one fetched from database.

```
var d = [[946699200000, 315.71], [949377600000, 317.45], [951969600000, 317.50], [957240000000, 315.86], [952056000000, 314.93], [983592000000, 313.19], [1033617600000, 313.34]];
```

Answer (score 2):

The AJAX call is asynchronous so all code that relies on its response must be placed in the callback function. Try this:

```
var d;
var arr = [];

$(function() {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'query_sales.php',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                arr.push([item.datey, +item.bv]);
            }); 
            d = arr; //JSON.stringify(arr);

            console.log(d); // use console.log to debug

            $.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
                xaxis: { mode: "time" }
            });

            $("#whole").click(function () {
                $.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
                    xaxis: { mode: "time" }
                });
            });
        }
    });

    // Add the Flot version string to the footer
    $("#footer").prepend("Flot " + $.plot.version + " &ndash; ");
});
```